# git does not recognize renamed file with only a change in case

Tags: php, git, github, case-sensitive

So today I encountered something really funny with git.

I had a file called `emoController.php` in my git repository.

I then renamed it to `EmoController.php` **Only change was the case**

I hit `git status` but the file was not marked as changed or renamed.

So I had to do a small hack by renaming it to something totally different, making a commit and renaming it to my original intention.

Is that an issue with `git` or is there something I should do?

Comment: are you on windows or another operating system?

Comment: On a mac @DanielA.White